# Presentation class in Jelly Bean Plus is not intercepting onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, touch-event, android-4.2-jelly-bean, display-manager

I am developing an android application, which displays some unique content on secondary display.
Presentation class is newly introduced in Jelly Bean Plus(4.2.1).
It is a special kind of dialog whose purpose is to present content on a secondary display
I am testing my application using secondary displays simulator which can be opened from settings - developer options
Now I would like to intercept touch events on secondary display. Have a look at my presention class

```
public class NewPresentation extends Presentation {

    public NewPresentation(Context outerContext, Display display) {
        super(outerContext, display);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_preview);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

But this onTouchEvent is not firing, when I touch somewhere on the secondary display.

I doubt that, as Presentation extends Dialog, which cannot intercept touch events(not sure), so does Presentation class

Is there any way to make Presentation class to intercept touch events? Please help me.

Comment: Did anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: hi, I am checking this feature, too.
and IMHO, Presentation probably should not be used this way.
in real scenario (not the simulator), there probably be no input event s from the "second display".

Comment: There is possibility that the second display may introduce input events....

Answer (score 0):

As Presentation class is extends to Dialog, and dialog itself is clickable you can have touch events from your presentation class. I tried sample app on device having secondary display and touch input enabled and it worked. Your secondary display may be dont  to have touch support